# script to submit ten jobs and wait to complete and resubmit next ten process to complete?

Tags: shell

How can I need to submit many jobs in parallel (say batch of ten each) and wait for them to complete and then resubmit next ten so on....?

```
array=( $(ls -1 window/*realign_win*.txt ) ) ;
echo ${#array[@]};

#for e in ${!array[*]}
for (( e=0; e<="${#array[@]}"; e++ ))
 do
#   echo "$e" ;
   for n in {0..9}
    do

      if [[ $e -gt ${#array[@]} ]]
         then
      echo $e, ${#array[*]};
          break;
      else

      echo $e, ${#array[*]};

    j=$(($e+$n)) ;
       echo "didel-1.01-linux-64bit --analysis indels --doDiploid --bamFile $i --ref Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.62.fa --varFile ${array[$j]}  --libFile ${i}_didel_output.libraries.txt --outputFile ${array[$j]}.didel_stage3" ;
    #e=$(($e+1)) ;
      echo $e;
      fi
      done &

wait

     done

 done
```

Please give suggestions to make it work, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still using a shell script, something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

jobs=`jot 25`
echo $jobs

set -- $jobs
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
    pids=""
    for i in `jot 10`; do
        [ $# == 0 ] && break
        job=$1
        shift

        echo start $job && sleep 3 && echo finish $job &
        pids="$pids $!"
    done
    wait $pids
done

echo done
```

**EDIT** Change `continue` to `break`.  Thanks @glennjackman

Comment: `break` would be better than `continue` here.

Comment: @glennjackman you are correct. `continue` will still step through any remaining iterations of `for i ...` just returning to the top of the loop when it hits the `continue`.  `break` will break out of the loop immediately.

Answer (score 5):

[Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) can be used to parallelize work in Perl, and can be told to limit the maximum number of simultaneous workers.

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

use constant MAX_WORKERS => 10;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->($MAX_PROCESSES);
for my $item (@work) {
   my $pid = $pm->start() and next;

   ...

   $pm->finish();
}
```

[threads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads) and [forks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks) provides an alternate interface. The choice of modules affect whether threads or child processes are used.

```
use threads;  # or: use forks;
use Thread::Queue qw( );

use constant MAX_WORKERS => 10;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @threads;
for (1..MAX_WORKERS) {
   push @threads, async {
      while (my $item = $q->dequeue()) {
         ...
      }
   };
}

$q->enqueue(@work);
$q->enqueue(undef) for 1..@threads;
$_->join() for @threads;
```